# Differential Equations by Complex Substitution

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have to solve $y'' + 9y = \sin(3t) + 2\sin(4t)$ where $y$ is real.

Since $\sin(3t) = Im(e^{3it})$ and $\sin(4t) = Im(e^{4it})$. Can I instead solve for complex $z$ such that $z'' + 9z = e^{i3t} + 2e^{i4t}$ and say $x = Im(z)$?

Could you please help me find the error in the below solution:

Setting $z = e^{\lambda i}$ gives $\lambda^2 + 9 = 0$ giving $\lambda = \pm 3i$. So complementary function is $z = Ae^{3it} + Be^{-3it}$. Complementary function for $x$ is $Im(Ae^{3it} + Be^{-3it}) = A\sin(3t) - B\sin(3t)$. But since $A,B$ are constants, let $C = A-B$. Complementary function is $C\sin(3t)$. But shouldn't the complementary function be of form $D\cos(3t) + E\sin(3t)$?

Comment: Your $A, B$ should be complex #s and hence $Im(Ae^{3it} + Be^{-3it}) \not= A\sin(3t) - B\sin(3t)$

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Do you think there is a way to fix my solution by considering this (without introducing too many variables)?

Comment: Using [Variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#General_second-order_equation), one arrives at $$y(t)=c_1 \sin(t) + c_2 \cos(t) -\frac18 \sin(3t) -\frac{2}{15} \sin(4 t).$$ Now, if $z$ solves your equation then $y= \operatorname{Im}z$ solves the original equation but I am not sure if the converse is true.

Comment: I have got $$y(t)=c_1cos(3t)+c_2\sin(3t)$$ and for the particular solution make the ansatz $$y_p=A\cos(4t)+B\sin(4t)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Oops, you are right (I dropped the $9$ in front of $y$), so the corect solution is $$c_1 \cos(3t)+c_2 \sin(3t)-\frac{\cos(t)}{42}\cdot(-7t+14t\cos(2t)-24\sin(t)+24\sin(3t))=c_1 \cos(3t)+c_2 \sin(3t) + \frac27 \sin(4 t) + \frac16 t \cos(3 t)$$ as determined by variation of parameters

Comment: @Confuse, see the answer posted below.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the characteristic equation of the complementary equation is
$$ \lambda^2+9= 0$$
which has two roots $\pm 3i$ and hence
$$ y_c=c_1\cos(3t)+c_2\sin(3t). $$ 
The forcing is $\sin(3t)+2\sin(4t)$ which is the imaginary part of $e^{3it}+2e^{4it}$ and hence the complex form of DE is
$$ z''+9z=e^{3it}+2e^{4it}. $$
So a particular solution should have the following form $z_p=Ate^{3it}+Be^{4it}$ and hence one has
$$ (A(6i-9t)e^{3it}-16Be^{4t})+9(Ate^{3t}+Be^{4t})=e^{3t}+2e^{4t}$$
Comparing the coefficients of $^{3t}$ and $e^{4t}$, one has
$$ 6i A=1,-7B=2 $$
or
$$ A=-\frac i6,B=-\frac27. $$
So
$$ z_p=-\frac i6t e^{3it}-\frac27 e^{4it}=\frac1{6}t(\sin(3t)-i\cos(3t))-\frac27(\cos(4t)+i\sin(4t)) $$
whose is 
$$ y_p=-\frac1{6}t\cos(3t)-\frac27\sin(4t). $$
Thus a general solution is
$$ y=y_c+y_p=c_1\cos(3t)+c_2\sin(3t)-\frac1{6}t\cos(3t)-\frac27\sin(4t).$$

Comment: In the third last row of your solution, $\frac16$ became $\frac{1}{16}$. Also, my sign for the particular solution seems to be wrong (I might have made a sign error somewhere)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch, thanks, it is a typo.

Comment: You might want to fix the exponents, they somehow partially lost the complex unit.